# object deletion with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a todo-list using javascript and want to create a Remove button. how should I do the method to make it happen

I just want to perform this operation with the help of the button.

```js
let id = 3;
let todos = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Javascript"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Vue"
  }
];

function render() {
  flen = todos.length;
  text = "<ul id=myUL>";
  for (i = 0; i < flen; i++) {
    text +=
      "<li id=myLI>" +
      todos[i].title +
      "<button style=float:right onClick=removeElement()> Remove </button> " +
      "</li>";
  }
  text += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
render();

//HERE A METHOD

function removeElement() {}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: What should remove button do? please add more details and the code that you currently have.

Comment: You need to present actual code, otherwise it is impossible to answer

Comment: Typically you would have an array of "tasks", the action would be to `array.splice()` at the appropriate index. Can't say more because you have provided nothing yourself. Note - A Todo app is the default training app. There are more training videos on this out there than porn websites. Maybe Google it?

Comment: One way to remove an element from an array is to call [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on it.

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57107998/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide us with a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this eventListener I created

It listens for any click in the DEMO div and removes the parent LI if the click was on the button - it is called delegation and I prefer that in vanilla JavaScript and jQuery when you have a list of things in a container.

Updated to remove the id.

I have given an alternative to the filter in the other answer

```js
let id = 3;
let todos = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Javascript"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Vue"
  }
];

function render() {
  text = "<ul id=myUL>";
  todos.forEach(todo =>{ 
    text +=
      "<li id=myLI>" +
      todo.title +
      '<button type="button" data-id="'+todo.id+'" class="rem"> Remove </button>' +
      "</li>";
  })
  text += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
render();
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches(".rem")) {
    tgt.closest("li").remove(); // or tgt.parentElement.parentElement.remove() for older browsers
    todos.splice(todos.findIndex(el => el.id = tgt.id), 1); // or use filter
    console.log(todos)
  }  
})
```

```css
.rem { float: right }
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: remove it from the array also, don't want to make unwanted bugs later

Comment: @Sumith Splease see update for an improved version that only deletes from the array when the button is clicked. Missed to bracket that before

Answer (score 2):

You need to be able to identify each `li` element properly by setting an id for each inside the for loop.

Then you need to pass that same id to your `removeElement()` function

Then in your remove, function you can retrieve the `li` element using `getElementById` and delete it using [node.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

```js
let id = 3;
let todos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Javascript"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Vue"
  }
];
function render() {
  flen = todos.length;
  text = "<ul id=myUL>";
  for (i = 0; i < flen; i++) {
    text +=
      "<li id=\"" + todos[i].id + "\">" +
      todos[i].title +
      "<button style=float:right onClick=removeElement(" + todos[i].id + ")> Remove </button> " +
      "</li>";
  }
  text += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
render();

//HERE A METHOD

function removeElement(idToRemove) {
  // Remove the li element
  document.getElementById(idToRemove).remove();
  
  // Remove the element from the array
  todos = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== idToRemove);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give your function a parameter called `event`, then inside the function, you can get a reference to the clicked button with `event.target`.
From there, you can "walk" up the DOM tree using `Element.parentNode` and you can remove a particular child of a particular HTML element with `Element.removeChild(childToRemove)`.

So it could look like:

```
function removeElement(event){ // The parameter can have any name, but "event" is convenient
  const button = event.target,
        li = button.parentNode,
        ul = li.parentNode;
  ul.removeChild(li);
}
```

Note that you would need to pass the click event as an argument when the function is called (like `onClick=removeElement(event)`) so the function can know what you mean by `event.target`.

Comment: If you must have inline event handling then passing (this) and have a data-attribute is better in my opinion

Comment: Agreed. My idea here was to keep it very simple because the OP's sample code doesn't show a high level of understanding yet. (Eg, building HTML Elements crudely by using strings instead of using `createElement`, `createTextNode`, and `appendChild`.)

Comment: I think `function removeElement(button){ 
        const li = button.parentNode,
        ul = li.parentNode;
  ul.removeChild(li);
}` is simpler than using the event - and `button.closest("li")` even simpler

Comment: Yes. Very basic event handling was the Gem of Knowledge I picked to feature in this answer (along with the `Element.parentNode` property and the `Element.removeChild` method.) My first draft basically just added enough code to make it work, without teaching much of anything, and I decided to try to make it more educationally useful without being overwhelming. Perhaps I didn't strike quite the right balance.